# React Admin - How to disable validation onChange

Tags: javascript, react-admin, react-final-form, final-form

I'm using `react-admin`, and I have a huge form, with a bunch of custom validation. It's very slow, even with the build version.

I tried to find a way to disable the validation on **change** and to have it only on **blur** or **submit**. But I have not found a solution or even workaround.

Every time a key is pressed in one of my input text (for example), the validation is triggered multiple times, and it takes a while for the letter to appear.

That's why I want to disable the validation on change.

Here's an example of one of my forms, every letter I write in one of my `FormTab`, the "validate me" is showing.

```js
export const ThemeCreate: FC = (props: any) => (
  <Create {...props} title="ui.themes.create" mutationMode="pessimistic">
    <TabbedForm
      toolbar={<GenericCreateToolbar />}
      validateOnBlur
      warnWhenUnsavedChanges
      validate={() => {
        console.log('validate me!');
      }}
    >
      <MainFormTab />
      <TranslationsFormTab />
    </TabbedForm>
  </Create>
);
```

Comment: please share the form code you're using

Comment: I edited my post with an example.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `validateOnBlur={true}` prop in the form component.

This prop is from final-form's `<Form>` component, see the last one in this doc page https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FormProps

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

But I already tried it, and with `react-admin` it doesn't seem to disable the validation on change.